# Can you cast Dispossess on an opponent's land (e.g., Mountain) if that opponent controls Mycosynth Lattice?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If an opponent has a [Mycosynth Lattice](https://scryfall.com/card/bbd/241/mycosynth-lattice) in play and is playing Izzet (for example), would you be able to cast [Dispossess](https://scryfall.com/card/akh/86/dispossess?utm_source=discord) and choose 'Mountain' if the opponent has at least one in play (This mountain would then be an artifact because of Mycosynth and would satisfy the 'choose an artifact card' requirement) and then subsequently exile all the opponent's remaining copies of 'Mountain' from his deck?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you cannot use Dispossess to name cards that do not have "Artifact" in its printed type line. When choosing a **card name** you pick cards based on the oracle text of the physical card, regardless of what other effects on the battlefield. Mycosynth Lattice is simply irrelevant to Dispossess.

Oddly enough, the relevant rule even lists Dispossess as an example:

> 201.3a If a player is instructed to choose a card name with certain characteristics, the player must choose the name of a card whose Oracle text matches those characteristics. (See rule 108.1.)
>
> ***Example**: Dispossess reads, in part, “Choose an artifact card name.” The player can choose the name of any artifact card, even one that’s not legal in the format of the current game. The player can’t choose Island, even if an Island on the battlefield has been turned into artifact by some effect.*

Comment: Splinter, Scour, and Eradicate *do* allow you to remove basic lands if that land has been given the correct type. That's because they target permanents.

Comment: Indeed, for those cards the restriction is on the original target, not the searched card names. There are oracle rulings on those cards clarifying that. (Those are part of a very interesting [cycle](https://tagger.scryfall.com/tags/card/cycle-uds-lobotomy-spell))

Comment: This is only true because Mycosynth Lattice only changes the type of cards on the battlefield. If you had a card that caused a similar effect that effected colorless cards rather than artifact cards, I'm pretty sure it'd be able to hit cards turned colorless by Mycosynth Lattice.

Comment: @nick012000 I disagree. Because it the search by name rule above uses Oracle text (as statically defined on Gatherer) the Lattice cannot affect the official copy of the card. Which means you can't find it. If the effect searched for cards by the card characteristics (like Green Sun's Zenith) instead of by name the Lattice would be relevant. Simply put the set of Colorless cards you can name is https://scryfall.com/search?q=color%3Ac and only official errata and new cards can change that set.

Comment: @nick012000 this would only work with an effect said something like "all _ are now artifact cards" (which would be incredibly weird and unlikely to make it outside an Un-* set imo) .. a subtle variation which is much more likely would be a replacement effect stating something like "if an effect requires you to name an artifact card, you may choose instead to name _"